# Unit Testing Angular with Jasmine : Trigger a click on a button

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine

I'm testing a component within my Angular app:

```
it('should not save empty alert after click on save button (async)', async(() => {
            fixture.detectChanges();
            fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
                let Btn = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#btn-createAlert')).nativeElement;
                comp.setCurrentAlert({});
                expect(comp.getCurrentAlert().title).toBeUndefined();
                expect(comp.getCurrentAlert().shops).toBeUndefined();
                // click(saveBtn); ???
                saveBtn.trigger('click');
                fixture.detectChanges();
                expect(saveSpy.calls.any()).toBe(false, 'alertService.saveAlert called');
                expect(saveAlertShopsSpy.calls.any()).toBe(false, 'alertService.saveAlertShops called');
                expect(loadAllSpy.calls.count()).toBe(1, 'alertService.getAllAlerts called only on ngOnInit');
            });
        }));
```

Within my test case like you have seen , i'm getting the reference of my button :

```
let Btn = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#btn-createAlert')).nativeElement;
```

Not to get my test case working i need to trigger a click on it.

Unfortenately , i cannot find any native jasmine tool to do it .

The following suggestion is not working :

```
saveBtn.trigger('click');
```

And i don't want to import any external library to do it (neither **jquery** , nor **jasmine-matchers**)

**Any suggestions ?**